# How to access waypoint shortcuts with bower and gulp?

Tags: npm, bower, jquery-waypoints

I have installed waypoints with using bower.  I can see that there is a folder for shortcuts inside of its /lib folder, containing the shortcuts for infinite.js inview.js and sticky.js.  My question is how I can actually access them in my project using bower.

I am using gulp to package all of my JavaScript for this project, so I am using "main-bower-files" to compile all of the library javascript files into a single file.

I have modified the bower.json so that waypoints will use the jquery version by doing the following

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "overrides" : {
    "waypoints" : {
      "main": "lib/jquery.waypoints.js"
    }
  }
```

But I do not know how I can include the /shortcuts/inview.js using this method.  Is it possible to use npm or bower to get access to these files?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just add it to `"main"` I would think:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
},
"overrides" : {
  "waypoints" : {
    "main": [
      "lib/jquery.waypoints.js",
      "lib/shortcuts/sticky.js"
    ]
  }
}
```